# 13.10 desktop install hangs on emachine

Tags: upgrade, 13.10

Wanted to try Ubuntu on 2 Pentium D dual core emachine computers I have. (Only half a Gig I think, might have upgraded, will check.) Found 13.10 needs a DVD burnt which I didn't have so I loaded an old 6.x CD, thought I could upgrade it live from there. Able to load/use 6.x overwriting XP just fine. Couldn't figure how to upgrade it live and machine won't boot from USB. Then I got DVDs, a burner & burnt a 13.10 32 bit desktop, but it hangs on language selection overwriting 6.x. Saw other posts advising to remove USB kbd. Am using PS/2 kbd and mouse. Was able to bring it up on 13.10 in "trial" mode and tried to do the install from there and it hung same place.

UPDATE: the machine had 1.5G in it and it's a 2.66G processor.
I tried Lubuntu 13.10 and it hung at the same place.
Both Ubuntu & Lubuntu 13.10 would run from the disk.
I tried something I thought wouldn't work (loading the emachine's hard drive on a different computer) and it boots and most of the apps work but the network won't connect. I figure that is because the install was built with the wrong nic but it's not real clear how to fix that and I imagine sound and other on board stuff won't work right. Oh and I couldn't set the resolution so that I could gracefully shutdown the machine without bringing up a command prompt. So I figure it's probably not worth trying to fix all the stuff that was built incorrectly by installing on a different computer.

So there has to be something that is keeping it from loading.
Guess I'll try the earlier versions.

Comment: I'd imagine that you'll have trouble getting Ubuntu to run on that machine with only 500Mb ram, look here for information on choosing a suitable flavour for your machine. http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the specifications of your machines are below the recommended for Ubuntu 13.10. I'd suggest to install Lubuntu 13.10 on your machines due to the fact that this version (Lubuntu) is much lighter than Ubuntu and would run much better on the machines you have. What you tell (behavior of the installation) says that you are very low on RAM for a normal Ubuntu installation.